# PhoneGap Camera - How to save base64 image into local storage or WebSQL?

Tags: javascript, cordova, camera, local-storage

I'm trying to save the **base64** image into local storage or WebSQL, but it will only display the image and stuck there after the "Save Into Local Storage" message has displayed.

**Code:-**

```
<div id="photoImage"></div>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="capturePhoto()" style="margin-bottom: 5px">Capture</a>

<script>
function capturePhoto(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    });
}

function onSuccess(imageData){
    var image = document.getElementById("photoImage");
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    alert("Save Into Local Storage");
    //Save into local storage
    localStorage.setItem("imageData", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
    alert("DONE");
}

function onFail(e) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + e);
}
</script>
```

The plugin:-

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="1.2.0" source="pgb" />
```

Comment: `localStorage` will allow you to store only 2.5MB to 5MB max depending on browser capability. It mayn't be a better way to store `base64` code in `localStorage`. I faced so may problems by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

change the function onSuccess

```
function onSuccess(imageData){
    var image = document.getElementById("photoImage");
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

    alert("Save Into Local Storage");
    //Save into local storage
    localStorage.setItem("imageData", imageData);
    alert("DONE");
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: localStorage.setItem("imageData", imageData); change this line